# How would I go about making a draggable grid of custom shaped tiles in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For a game I want to make a grid of shapes that are adjacent (nicely bordering each other) and are draggable/swappable. For example a grid of hexagons or triangles. I have no idea how to go about it. Can I do this with collectionView or do I need to use spriteKit or something else? Any ideas for a direction to go would be much appreciated.

Update:
so I did a sort of proof of concept after some googling using UIBezierPaths to draw a grid of triangle shapes and UIBezierPath.contains(CGPoint) function to get dragging working. I made a UIView subclass TriangleView to draw the triangles, but there is an issue I've run into. Two adjacent triangles that form a square have the same frame and so the transparent part of one is always on top of the other triangle. the pan/tap gestures therefore are hitting the transparent part rather than the visible triangle underneath, any ideas how to ignore the transparent part and hit the triangle underneath. Right now basically I'm not acting on the gesture if it hits the transparent part (so it only moves when touching the actual shape)

[What this all looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5mm.png)

the code for the pan gesture recognizer:

```
@objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    var shouldDrag:Bool = false

    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: (sender.view! as! TriangleView))
    shouldDrag = (sender.view! as! TriangleView).hitTest(tapLocation: CGPoint(x: tapLocation.x, y: tapLocation.y)) //returns whether tap is in UIBezierPath portion of UIView and not transparent part

    if shouldDrag{
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: (sender.view! as! TriangleView))
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        (sender.view! as! TriangleView).center = CGPoint(x: (sender.view! as! TriangleView).center.x + translation.x, y: (sender.view! as! TriangleView).center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Update Again:
so after some searching I found that a better option would be to override this method in my UIView subclass:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if triangleBezierPath.contains(point){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

so now I don't even need to check for this during the gesture, the transparent/part outside the triangle is completely ignored. It seems to work a bit smoother this way too. Do you think this would be better done with SpriteKit or CollectionView? I still need to figure out how to swap the shapes on overlapping drag

Comment: I think you would need to use SpriteKit to do this

Comment: do you want something like this https://github.com/akashraje/BidirectionalCollectionViewLayout/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I just want a grid of non-squares where I can drag one shape and swap it for another cell in the grid, I don't think I will need scrolling

Comment: I think the "grid" is what is throwing me off here because a grid contains rectangles.  views are always going to be rectangles in some way or form,  so you are most likely going to need to do spritekit since you can work with Paths a lot easier.  This of course is still going to be a lot of work because there is no easy way to detect when 2 non squares are overlapping.

Comment: For hexagon shapes,if you are doing a hexagon board, and all of the shapes are the same size, then a collection view is possible, You just need to have each cell overlap into the adjacent cells, and shift the even cells halfway the size of a cell.  Definitely not an easy task, but accomplishable